# Can a for loop be used as a timer if written like this? (code below)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

This is my concept for the timer, I just wanted to get some opinions on it before I implement it into Unity:

```
int Minute = 60; 
for (int Second = 1; Second < Minute; Second += Minute / 60 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Would this go up once a second or because im using Time.deltaTime would it still go up frame by frame?

Comment: Would something like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html work for you?

Comment: It would count up as fast as it possibly can.  Nothing is currently stopping it from waiting until the next frame to start the next iteration of the loop.  Of course, rather than changing that, you should just use a built in timer mechanism, it'll be a lot more efficient and simpler than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @Servy I was afraid of that, is there any way to fix that? (I know NOT using time.deltaTime would work but something other than that)

Comment: @JustinDev Why are you trying to roll your own timer?  Why are you not using the built in mechanisms to accomplish this?

Comment: @Servy I didnt know there were built in mechanisms for this, and i also thought it might be fun to make it without those.

Comment: @WouterdeKort oh ok! Ill check this out, Im not familiar with courotines but ill look into it!

Comment: That code is a good way to cook your CPU ;) As others have said there are built in tools to help. Do you want the timer to just track time, or do you want to do something after a period of time?

Comment: You have created what is known as a "tight loop". It's essentially an expensive way of converting electricity to heat.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function that needs a timer a coroutine like this:

```
    IEnumerator YourFunction(int waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime); //Also accepts float values
    //do something
}
```

Keep in mind that you cannot call coroutines like normal functions, so you will need to use:

```
StartCoroutine(YourFunction(3)); //For example, this will wait 3 seconds.
```

Also IEnumerator is within the System.Collections library.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, don't use this. This would cause hundreds of problems and poor performance.

You have a few options like:

```cs
//Import Library.
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

//...

//Freeze the code for 1 Sec.
Thread.Sleep(1000);

//OR create a Timer (Better Solution)

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code run after 2 Sec.
        //aTimer.Enabled = false;
        //To Stop the Timer.
    }
```

But... If you're using Unity, I can't help you, this solution works for Net Framework and Core.

If you use Unity you will have to search deeper or even "try" to use this code.

Comment: Dont use `Thread.Sleep` in Unity or game go boom.

Answer (score -1):

I'd reccomend using a built in mechanism for a timer.

Where there is nothing happening inside of your for loop, it's going to just add the current second over and over again, causing the loop to act like it almost didn't exist. Here's what I recommend if you insist using your own timer instead of something pre built.

```
for(int seconds = 0; seconds < 60; seconds++)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    
    //Whatever code you want to be executed
    
    if(DateTime.Now.Second == startTime.Second)
    {
        //Loop will add one, so if a second hasn't passed, remove one
        seconds--;
    }
    else if(DateTime.Now.Second > startTime.Second + 1)
    {
        //If more than one second has passed, add the time that will
        //be missed by just adding one
        seconds += DateTime.Now.Second - (startTime.Second + 1);
    }
}
```